# Prove that $N(T)\subseteq R(T)$ if $R(T) \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $T: V\rightarrow V$ is a linear transformation over the complex field and $V$ is finite dimensional. Every eigenvalue of $T$ is zero and $nullity(T)=1$. Show that $N(T)\subseteq R(T)$ if $R(T) \neq 0$.

I think the problem asks to prove that if $\alpha\in N(T)$, then there exists $\beta\in V$ such that $T(\beta)=\alpha$. But where do I use that the eigenvalues of $T$ are zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all eigenvalue of $T$ is zero, $T$ is nilpotent, or $T^n=0$. There exists a $k\leqslant n$, such that $T^k(\alpha)=0,T^{k-1}(\alpha)\ne0$.

Since $T(T^{k-1}(\alpha))=T^k(\alpha)=0$, $T^{k-1}(\alpha)\in N(T)$. It also spans $ N(T)$ for $\dim N(T)=1$. Since $T^{k-1}(\alpha)\in R(T), N(T)\subset R(T)$.

Comment: Did you use Cayley-Hamiltonian theorem implicitly?

Comment: Cayley-Hamiltonian theorem is used implicitly in $T^n=0$.

Answer (score 2):

It's not true unless you assume that $V$ is finite dimensional.
For example, let $V$ be the space of all polynomials, $T(p)(x) = x (p(x) - p(0))$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $N(T)$ is not a subspace of $R(T)$ I.e. $N(T)\cap R(T)=\{0\}$. Then $\ker(T|_{R(T)})=0$ and $T|_{R(T)}$ is an isomorphism, but then that contradicts the assumption that all eigenvalues of $T$ are 0. So $N(T)\cap R(T)\neq 0$ and since $\text{dim}N(T)=1$ we have $N(T)\subseteq R(T)$.